# Is there any explanation of the "Lightspeed War?"

Tags: the-green-leopard-plague

I was just re-reading ["The Green Leopard Plague"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?102270) by Walter Jon Williams, and it made me remember that I was curious about the details of the "Lightspeed War" that is referenced a few times as part of the historical back-story of the setting.

The story mentions that billions of people died, many official records were destroyed, and that most prisoners were killed, but that may simply be a reflection of the questions that the protagonist in the story was asking.  (For example, it may also be the case that people in hospitals were killed and medical records were destroyed, but since that wasn't related to the research she was doing, she never mentioned it.)

**Is there any explanation - in related works, or comments from the author - as to what the "Lightspeed War" was?**

Any of the following details would be of interest:

- When did the war happen?
- Who started the war and why?
- Who were they fighting against?
- Why was it given the name "Lightspeed War?"
- Where and how was it fought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find anything more recent at this stage but as of 2004 the stories *Lethe* and  *The Green Leopard Plague* are set after the Lightspeed War but very little detail is given, [this statement from the author](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.arts.sf.written/NsRsiFnfAak) tells us that at that time the details had not been hammered out and he isn't giving away any details that he does know.

> The Lightspeed War is part of the implied background of the "College of 
>   Mystery" sequence, which at the moment consists of only two stories, 
>   "Lethe" and "Green Leopard."
>
> I haven't written any stories actually set in the war, because I haven't 
>   figured out a war to make any such stories as interesting as stories set in 
>   the society that follows it. [...]
>
> On the off chance that I *do* figure out a way to make such a story 
>   interesting, I don't want to give away a lot of what the war was about.
>
> <sub>Walter Jon Williams [post to rec.arts.sf.written](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.arts.sf.written/NsRsiFnfAak/MnZ1oVeaLLkJ) 2004/03/01</sub>

Comment: Thanks for finding this.  I've edited in the relevant portion of his response in case Google groups gets messed up some more in the future.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks I should have done that myself, obviously not thinking as clearly as I could be today.

Answer (score 1):

As of [January 2022](http://www.walterjonwilliams.net/2022/01/eye-catching/) WJW has written a third short in this universe, "[Pinocchio](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?850076)" but still hasn't written anything directly about the Lightspeed War:

> Though it’s not explicitly stated, Earth’s population is greatly reduced in the College of Mystery sequence of stories, including “The Green Leopard Plague” and “Lethe.” This is following an event I called the “Lightspeed War”— I know what the event was, but **I haven’t yet found a way to make it interesting enough as a piece of fiction to write about it.**

Comment: The IMDB link for "Pinocchio"'s appearance shows the atory came out in 2008. So maybe 2008 is a better date to use than the 2022 blog date.

Comment: @Spencer Hmm.  You're right, it's not clear.  The source for the previous entry was dated 2004, so it was published after that; that there's only the 1 more story is current as of 2022...   It didn't sound wrong as I was writing it, but let me think about the best way to rephrase this.